# How to find from which app the user clicked my app extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-safari, ios-app-extension

I have an app extension which is featured in browsers, I would like to know from which app the user clicks my app extension.

e.g Say the user clicks my extension in a chrome browser , I would like to know whether it was chrome browser or safari.

The below code doesn't provide what I need. Any pointers in this regard will be appreciated.

```
(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

          NSLog(@"Source Application is : %@", sourceApplication);

    }
```

Comment: What does say your log in case of Safari or Chrome? In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` what log the `launchOptions` parameters?

Comment: App Extension won't call your openURL. It will call code in your Extension Target. Are you talking about URL Schemes to launch your application?